# Synaptic on CentOS

Tags: centos, package-management, synaptic

There is quite useful program for managing packages in `Debian-based` operating systems. It is called `Synaptic`. Is there same program on `Red Hat-based` systems, such as `CentOS`?

Comment: There is `packagekit`. And it should be installed by default (at least on the desktop spins). It should at least be available on Fedora and Centos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yum Extender](http://www.yumex.dk) is a GUI for the yum packages manager used in Fedora, RHEL, Centos and others. The goal with the application is to give easy access to many of the powerful features in yum.

---

**Options**

- Translation - system localisation
- Search specified package
- Manage queue
- Choose repository
- Yum history view
- etc.

---

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: yumex-dnf is no longer in the default repos. Is it dead? What was it replaced by?

Answer (score 2):

There is a GUI package management tool called [pirut](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-graphical-rpm.html) mentioned in the CentOS documentation.

Comment: (That link is dead.)